# PHP get variable from url modified with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
example.com/en/hk/myAccount?Ref=CC0000008
```

And my .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^(chin|en)/(hk|kw)/myAccount/?$    user_account.php?lang=$1&loc=$2& [NC,L] #SHOW USER ACCOUNT
```

So I want to get now the variable `ref` passed on the url but when I `print_r` the variabel `$_GET` I only get the variables in the `.htaccess` file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `QSA` flag

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(chin|en)/(hk|kw)/myAccount/?$ user_account.php?lang=$1&loc=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Output:

```
Array ( [lang] => en [loc] => hk [Ref] => CC0000008 )
```

The flag `QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, appended it.

The flag `L` means if the rule matches, don't process any more rules below this one.

The flag `NC` means case-insensitive, that is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

[Apache RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: but what happen if the variable is not 'Ref' ... in the future the variable is 'ammount' for example?

Comment: Updated. just remove `&Ref=$3` and you can send any number of parameters with any name

Comment: yes my friend, you are a genius! add to your answer that the thing I need to do is change the flag to QSA... so someone in the future can understand easier